# File for group of views but not for all views

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have MVC/Razor application with two controllers lets say One and Two, and follow MVC conventions I have folder Views/One and Views/Two. In folders one and two I have lot of views on each folder **that have the same Layout**. In the Scripts folder I added two javascript files lets say One.js and Two.js. is there a way to make the functions that in One.js to be in all the views in the folder Views/One but not in the folder Views/Two but not declaring the script file in every view?

Comment: `not declaring the script file in every view` mean `<script src="one.js"/>` in every main_view.cshtml?

Comment: yes because I have about 30 views in the folder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by creating a parial view and keep the changes in one place. This way you could make your changes simple instead of changing it in all 30 files as you said.

**_OneScript.cshtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/one.js")"></script>
```

In all your one's views you can add the below code. Final output will be same as equivalent to referring a script file in all pages, but changing the file name/ adding more can be manageable at one place

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/One/_OneScript.cshtml");}
```

Comment: Really nice idea, so you think there is no way how to do it without put code in all the views?

Comment: @ilayzeidman, there may be other way like creating our own html helper to inject the script in all the files. But that will be time consuming and quite difficult :)